# How to create, write and delete file or folder using PHP code in CentOS

Tags: php, centos, centos6

I have used `mkdir()` function for creating folder, `fopen()` and `fwrite()` function used for create and write file. Also I have used `unlink()` function for deleting file in PHP code.

```
mkdir($dirname, 0777);
$handle=fopen($dirname."/".$dbConf, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $data);
unlink('file');
```

This code working in Ubuntu, Windows OS but not Working in CentOS.

I have get error like `Permission Denied to unlink()`.

Comment: is there any error you got?

Comment: Did you forget to assign the handle ? it should be `$handle = fopen(...);`